# Cannot get last remaining Dynasty member

Tags: tropico-5

I'm stuck on finding the last dynasty member (currently have 6) and I need the final one for the final trophy to get the Platinum trophy.

I've found some forum posts mentioning that you can get a dynasty member in the start of the Colonial era and the Modern era (in Sandbox mode), after sending a dynasty member to Harvard university that gives you an option to take on a heir after a 'reckless night' done by the dynasty member.  I got one from the Colonial era, but did not get one from the Modern era.

I got a total of 6 in the campaign, but one was killed when I sent it off to negotiate with the rebels, so I was left with 5 when I finished the campaign.  Maybe this is why I'm stuck with 6?

I've also tried starting a new campaign with my dynasty members, but did not get the option to take on a heir after sending one of my dynasty members to Harvard.

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: I think the only way to get dynastys is to do what you mentioned. I don;t have the game for myself, but I tried to Google it for you - and I failed.

Answer (score -1):

I've done a bit of research (if you can call it that) and apparently sometimes replaying the first mission can fire up an event to give you another dynasty members, although I cannot vouch for this as I haven't played the game good luck tho

Maybe you should try completely resetting your game

Comment: I have already mentioned about this in my post. It doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: Sos, haven't played game so didn't know where you referenced that in your question :P.

Comment: Just got downvoted, I feel violated..

Comment: I didn't downvote you :/

Comment: @MacMac didn't say it was by you my dear friend <3